# error TS2339: Property 'getter' does not exist on type 'typeof ios'. in Nativescript 6 with angular

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Upgrade to latest version of Nativescript 6 from version 5 code start giving error of getter of ios in utils.
 Property 'getter' does not exist on type 'typeof ios'. in Nativescript 6 with angular.
This code is responsible for close keyboard at IOS.

Checked over official Docs not method is available 
https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/utils#ios

Also tried  getting error after run by Object property access
utils.ios.getter() is deprecated; use the respective native property instead
utils.ios['getter'](UIApplication, UIApplication.sharedApplication)

```js
utils.ios.getter(UIApplication, UIApplication.sharedApplication)
        .keyWindow
        .endEditing(true);
```

Getter should be available in ios utils

Answer (score 16):

`utils.ios.getter(...)` was already deprecated on {N} v5.4, probably it's removed in v6. You should directly access the property moving forward.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.endEditing(true);
```